I need to dockerize Symbol.RFID3.Host but I am getting error about: rfidapi32pc
I have a .net application, this is from my dockerfile:
# Copy the dependencies from the project directory to the Docker image
COPY ["RMAA.RFIDService/lib/Symbol.RFID3.Host.dll", "/app/dependencies/"]
COPY ["RMAA.RFIDService/lib/rfidapi32pc.dll", "/app/dependencies/"]

# Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the directory with the native DLLs
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/dependencies:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV PATH=/app/dependencies:$PATH

But when I run app I am getting this error message:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'rfidapi32pc.dll'
Is it doable? or I am wasting time?
Regards
